# Razor - How can I write the literal @?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Let's say I have this CSS embedded in my `Index.cshtml`:

```
.spinning {
    animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: spin2 1s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes spin {
    from { transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg); }
    to { transform: scale(1) rotate(360deg); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin2 {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

The above will not compile because `@` will be considered a Razor directive to execute C# code.

How can I tell the Razor engine to omit these `@`?

Comment: Prefix it with another @, so it will be @@